# How to combine these funcions (FILTER + IMPORTRANGE) in one?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, importrange, google-sheets-filter

I have all data in one sheet and I need to filter the imported data to another sheet. How can I do that in one function?

Function to filter data which I use:

```
=FILTER(A7:C,RIGHT(A7:A,7)="?id=999")
```

so how to combine this filter function with importrange function?

```
=IMPORTRANGE("URL", "Template!A16:C")
```

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Answer (score 0):

- in one go it would be like this:

  ```
  =FILTER(IMPORTRANGE("ID", "Template!A16:C"), 
   RIGHT(IMPORTRANGE("ID", "Template!A16:A"), 7)="?id=999")
  ```